# Escaping splatted variables in Powershell Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell, escaping

I'm trying to invoke another application (Beyond Compare) from Powershell which requires an @ in the typical command-line:

```
C:\deploy>bcompare @static.diff
```

I've found Powershell's Invoke-Expression, but when I try the following it gives me an error:

```
PS C:\deploy>Invoke-Expression "bcompare @static.diff"
Invoke-Expression : Cannot expand the splatted variable '@static'. Splatted variables
cannot be used as part of a property or array expression. Assign the result of the 
expression to a temporary variable then splat the temporary variable instead.
At line:1 char:18
    + Invoke-Expression <<<<  "bcompare @static.diff"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoPropertiesInSplatting,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

I can't get the @ to escape properly here. I've tried the `, @@, putting parts of the command in a temporary variable, but none of them did the trick.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
bcompare '@static.diff'
```

If in doubt, put it into a string :-)

```
PS Home:\> args '@static.diff'
argv[0] = "C:\Users\Joey\Batches\args.cmd"
argv[1] = @static.diff
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to double escape, because you are going through two levels of interpretation.  Only one ` will not work because it get parsed during the string creation.

```
Invoke-Expression "bcompare ``@static.diff"
```

Or as Joey said.

```
Invoke-Expression "bcompare '@static.diff'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now I see the multiple passes of interpretation that were tripping me up.

Comment: Multiple levels of interpretation are always a pain.  :)

Comment: That's usually the very best reason *not* to use `Invoke-Expression`. It's unnecessary here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into the same problem, I used a backtick to make the @-sign interpreted literally. I wanted to use double-quotes for variable handling as well:

> > Invoke-Expression "& bcompare `@$compareCommands $file1 $file2"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error on **npm install** on the windows command line

The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression.

```
npm install @neville.dabreo/greetingbot

The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression.
```

But single quotes resolved the problem

```
npm install '@neville.dabreo/greetingbot'
```

NOTE - Official NPM site doesn't mention a single quotes.

Comment: Using single quotes was already proposed in two prior answers.  Instead of posting a duplicate answer I think this should be a comment or, really, just a couple of upvotes on those answers.

Comment: Cheers, exactly what I was looking for :)